# What should do when a smooth effect looks linear In a GAM?

Tags: regression, modeling, generalized-additive-model

Recall the example in Wood, 2017 (Page.344), where a logistic GAM is fitted to a data set with some covariates all as smooth terms and then the estimated effects are plotted. Here is the effect of covariate `gly`:

[image]

`s(gly)` effect is significant, but appears to be linear. The question is whether we should insert `gly` as linear into the model (instead of smooth term) or not? Is it enough to decide for that only according the plot? Or we should also check changes in the model indices (e.g. ML score, AIC, adjusted R-sq, etc)?

- Wood, S. N. (2017). Generalized additive models: an introduction with R. CRC press.

Comment: What is your goal? Prediction, inference or visualization? For inference, the degrees of freedom used should be considered spent ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that the y-axis is plotted on log-odds scale if you use the default plot(gam,page=1,shade=TRUE). You can convert that back to the more intuitive probability scale by using the trans argument plot(gam,page=1,shade=TRUE,trans = plogis), which gives you the expected curve. https://noamross.github.io/gams-in-r-course/chapter4
[image: as attached]